# Performing a query using Typeahead + Bloodhound and FOSJsRoutingBundle in Symfony2

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm trying to setup Typeahead + Bloodhound to perform search with suggestions on a field. The HTML code for the field is as follow:

```
<div class="col-sm-10" id="products_forms">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Producto" id="ProductoForm_0_product_id" name="ProductoForm[0][product_id]" class="form-control typeahead">
</div>
```

I use two main functions from Symfony: one for return all the products and use this as a `prefetch` and the other for the filtered products. This is how the routes for that functions looks like:

```
 // the one I use as prefetch parameter in bloodhound
 * @Route("/get_products", name="all_products")

 // the one I use as remote
 * @Route("/get_products/{filter}", name="filter_products")
```

As you can see the first one didn't get any parameters since it returns all the products as JSON values but the second one takes `{filter}` as a argument for perform the `LIKE` and returns only the filtered products.

Now I don't know understand at all how Bloodhound works so I read the [docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md) and also for typeahead read the [docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md) and take a example from [here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote) the `Remote` one and made this code:

```
// Trigger typeahead + bloodhound
var products = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: Routing.generate('all_products'),
    remote: Routing.generate('filter_products', { 'filter' : '%query' })
});

products.initialize();
$('#products_forms .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'products',
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: products.ttAdapter()
});
```

Is that right? I mean when page loads I'll get all the products prefetched but if I type any on `.typeahead` element I'll get only the filtered ones? I don't know if `%query` is the right value I should pass to `filter_products` route in order to get the filtered values. Any help?

This is the first time I use Typeahead + Bloodhound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `remote: Routing.generate('filter_products', { 'filter' : '%query' })` with e.g.

```
var url = Routing.generate('filter_products', {filter: 'WILDCARD'});
// ... some code
remote: {
            url: url,
            wildcard: 'WILDCARD'
        }
```

That will generate a general url with the RoutingBundle first and takes 'WILDCARD' as your filter. Than tell bloodhound to use 'WILDCARD' on the url as placeholder and it will perfecly replace it with the entered query.

Comment: Hi, Can you please advise how can I pass an api-key here?